# What would be the best at home exercises I can do when I can't get to the gym?

Tags: strength-training, home-exercise, hiit

I'm 22, in college and I can't always get out to the gym as often as I'd like due to hours of it being open and my hours of availability.

I've no health problems, just out of shape. Very thin/lean build and I'd very much like to change that to solid fit base. I was looking into burpees, as an example, however I've no idea how many/ how long/ rest intervals/ etc.

Keep in mind I'm looking for at home workouts when I've no equipment at home and am looking for the best results regardless of how "hard" something is. If it's hard but it works fairly quickly then I'd be sure to reach for that workout.

I've no fat on my body to burn either so cardio/fat burn intensive exercises will not have the best results on me.

================================

Age: 22

Sex: M

Body Type: Thin/Lithe

Weight: Underweight, 103lbs or 46.72kgs

Typically able to properly hit the gym Tuesdays-Thursdays, maybe Monday or Friday as well.

Comment: How tall are you?

Comment: Best bet, have a look at http://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness and look at their recommended routines.

Answer (score 0):

Search youtube for home/body-weight exercises.

Here's some basic information to get you started:

- Push-Ups - Your go to Chest exercise (also works shoulder and triceps)
- Pull-Ups - For your Lats (Back) requires a pull-up bar (Search Australian pull-ups with a table if you don't have a bar)
- Squats - These are for your legs, don't skip these.
- Lunges - Also for the legs
- Dips - Chest/Triceps
- Military press - Shoulders
- Crunches/Russian-Twists/V-Ups - Ab exercises
- The **plank** - Abs and Back
- Mountain Climbers - Abs, Back, Legs, Shoulders

Look these up. There will be variations for increasing or decreasing difficulty.

If your interested in gaining muscle mass then keep each set in the 8 - 12 rep range. Change the difficulty of each exercise to keep you in that range (Meaning it should be hard to get to the 12th rep) Breaks should be no more than a minute. The amount of sets is subject to debate. If your a beginner I'd suggest more sets (if only to help you practice the movements more).

This should send you off on the beginning of your home body-weight training journey.